# Select items from database from specific year using timestamp

Tags: php, mysql, unix-timestamp

I was trying to figure out how to select all items with a timestamp from 2017. I have a database column that includes a timestamp of when the item was published, it looks like this "1506888905". I was wondering what I would have to do to the below code to have it select only items with a timestamp from X year. (2016, 2017 ect..)

```
SELECT * FROM my_db_table ORDER BY my_views_column DESC LIMIT 50;
```

The above code is what I'm using to get the first items with the highest amount of views. Now how would I go about selecting items only from a specific year if my timestamp column was named my_timestamp_column.

I've also come across another question like this on here that suggested using the below piece of code. But I've tried it with no luck so I imagine I'm doing something wrong.

```
SELECT * FROM my_db_table WHERE my_timestamp_column >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 YEAR) ORDER BY my_views_column DESC LIMIT 50;
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably do something like:

```
SELECT * FROM my_db_table WHERE YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(my_timestamp_column)) = 2017 ORDER by my_views_column DESC LIMIT 50;
```

`FROM_UNIXTIME` will convert your timestamp to a "Human Readable" date and `YEAR` will extract the year from it.

Comment: This has seemed to do the job for me, I'll have to wait and see if any issues arise. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

OR, You could use the between:

```
SELECT * FROM my_db_Table WHERE my_timestamp_column BETWEEN "2017-01-01 00:00:01" AND "2017-12-31 23:59:59";
```

hth

Ole Kristian Ek Hornnes